# Swagger UI is changing the protocol in the request from https to http

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

In the swaggerUI  it's default takes the 'http' but the actual API will support the 'https'
One possible way, *will remove the 'http' in the schema, but in local unable to test the 'https'*
so what is the possible solution for this issue?

Anyone have idea pls help me to find it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its evident from this [open issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1670) of [swagger-api/swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) in github, for you to use https in localhost, make a self signed certificate using openssl and make the browser trust your self signed certificate.

How to get self signed certificate for Apache is explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: yes,Tito you are right ...Thanks..Is this a only way?

Comment: @Ramyachinna if you want to have https in localhost, self signing is the only way. You cannot get a CA signed certificate for localhost by design.

Comment: Okay ..Thank you so much

Comment: @Ramyachinna I also found this tool recently to easily make localhost domain names.  

https://github.com/typicode/hotel

Comment: Another link for https localhost certificate https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec

Answer (score 6):

Just put it in your docs

```
schemes:
- "https"
- "http"
```

And you'll got select with provided schemes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your settings.py if you are using Django

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
```