# Swagger openapi redirect http to https

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

In my application we are using `openapi` to bootstrap swagger with default configurations.

Dependency we are using :
`org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9`

We are not using any json / yaml to specify open api specs.

The application is running on `https`, but swagger uses default protocol as `http`.

I've gone thru community answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646589/swagger-ui-is-changing-the-protocol-in-the-request-from-https-to-http) which suggest to edit json specs to configure the protocol.

But was wondering if there is any other way (may be any annotation) with which I can achive the same?

Please suggest.

Comment: Check out the suggestions in https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/118

Comment: @Helen, thanks. That was informative.

Answer (score 0):

Define @OpenAPIDefinition in main SpringBootApplication using openapi @ServerVariable as below:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "https://{host}",
variables = @ServerVariable(name = "host",
defaultValue = "hostname_sit",
allowableValues = {"hostname_sit","hostname_uat"}),
description = "Host name by environment")})
```